# How to make a selection PyMongo only unique records?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, nosql

How to make a selection PyMongo only unique records?

```
>>> db.houses.find({"street":{"$regex": "Fl", "$options":"i"}}).count()
107
>>> for item in db.houses.find({"street":{"$regex": "Fl", "$options":"i"}}):
...  print item["street"]
...
Flatbush Avenue
Flatbush Avenue
Flatbush Avenue
Flatlands Avenue
Flatlands Avenue
Flatlands Avenue
Flatlands Avenue
Flatlands Avenue
Flushing Avenue
Flushing Avenue
...more
```

How to get a unique record only "street" in response to a query? That is, to avoid duplicate records:

```
Flatbush Avenue
Flatlands Avenue
Flushing Avenue
```

Comment: You should have posted an example with English names. Some systems can't even display this. And this looks like Chinese to most people, anyway :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the docs - [Cursor.distinct](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.distinct) should do the trick:

```
db.houses.find({"street":{"$regex": "май", "$options":"i"}}).distinct("street")
```